# How to get gray background in R Markdown for plain text code fences?

Tags: css, r, r-markdown, markdown, xaringan

In xaringan all code fences for various programming languages display a gray background when I use the default YAML. The code fence background is gray, just like this:

```
---
title: "Presentation Ninja"
output:
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    lib_dir: libs
    nature:
      highlightStyle: github
      highlightLines: true
      countIncrementalSlides: false
---
```

There is an exception however when I insert plain text code fences:

````
```
Hi. I am plain text.
```
````

That code fence above renders as black text on a white background in my knitr xaringan output HTML slides. It does render as a code fence in *font style*, it just doesn't have the gray background. If I specify a syntax highlighting language (eg ```` ```r ````) it regains the gray background, but brings in R highlighting I don't want (eg bold words, colored numbers, etc).

In R Markdown do I need to specify some type of plain text syntax highlighting, to keep code fence style formatting with gray background? I've tried `text`, `hljs`, `rtf`, and none of those achieve the desired effect (plain text, black color font, gray background, no other highlighting).

Comment: I don't fully understand, what you want. Plain text with gray background in ```html_document``` output? Or in the ```xarigan```?

Comment: @manro yes, I'd like plain text with gray background. I can only get the gray background if I specify a language and syntax highlighting. Otherwise - for plain text - I get a white background, barely distinguishable from normal text (other than the font style).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this?

`````
---
title: "Presentation Ninja"
output:
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    lib_dir: libs
    nature:
      highlightStyle: github
      highlightLines: true
      countIncrementalSlides: false
---

```
Hi. I am plain text.
```

````markdown
Hi. I am plain text with gray background.
````
`````

[image]